# how to send mail from xampp localhost by a gmail account

Tags: php, email, xampp, localhost, sendmail.exe

Config settings in Xampp to send mails through gmail account

I am getting

> ```
> `Socket Error # 10061<EOL>Connection refused`
> ```

php.ini settings

> ```
> `SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
> smtp_port=587
> sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
> sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"`
> ```

sendmail.ini settings

> `smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
>      smtp_port=587
>      error_logfile=error.log
>      debug_logfile=debug.log
>      auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
>      auth_password=my-gmail-password
>      force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com`

Comment: i am using a proxy server in my college can that be the reason for it not working

Comment: It very well could be. Can you telnet smtp.gmail.com 587